onnxruntime c++, how to get human readable input name
when use onnxruntime-1.16.3 and I use following code
#include <iostream>
#include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>

int main() {
    // Path to the ONNX model
    const char *model_path = "/home/roroco/Downloads/mix/test_ai/resnet18-v1-7.onnx";

    // Create an ONNX Runtime environment
    Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "ONNXExample");

    // Create a session options object
    Ort::SessionOptions session_options;

    // Create an ONNX Runtime session
    Ort::Session session(env, model_path, session_options);

    // Get the input count of the model
    size_t input_count = session.GetInputCount();

    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;

    // Print the input names
    for (size_t i = 0; i < input_count; ++i) {
//        char *input_name = session.GetInputName(i, allocator);
        char *input_name = session.GetInputNameAllocated(i, allocator).get();
        std::cout << "Input name " << i << ": " << input_name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

it out Input name 0: ���UUU
when I switch to onnxruntime 1.12 and use session.GetInputName(i, allocator), it get can real input name "data"
in new onnxruntime, how to get human-readable input name

You assign result of get() of temporary std::unique_ptr returned from GetInputNameAllocated
function to input_name. Temporary goes out of scope on next line, destroys what it managed and so input_name is dangling pointer. Using it in output is undefined behavior.

I try following code
    std::string input_name = session.GetInputNameAllocated(i, allocator).get();
    auto input_name2 = session.GetInputNameAllocated(i, allocator).get();
    std::cout << "input_name:" << input_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "input_name2:" << input_name2 << std::endl;

the out is:
input_name:data
input_name2:

So I guess the session.GetInputNameAllocated(i, allocator) return ptr, and ptr is freed in before std::cout
so use
std::string input_name = session.GetInputNameAllocated(i, allocator).get();

work
